# PHP Serialize list of objects to json comming null

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array, serialization, encapsulation

I'm trying to pass a list of objects in php to a json but the output is not being as expected.

### Controller:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {

    require_once "../dao/SubstanciaDAO.php";
    require_once "../utils/php/Serialize.php"; // importing util to serialize list of objects

    if(array_key_exists("fetchAll",$_GET))
    {
        $subs = SubstanciaDAO::read(array("all"));//fetching list of objects
        if($subs) {
            $list = jsonSerializeList($subs);//this function is written bellow in another file

            if(isset($list))
                echo json_encode($list, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);//writting output
            else
                echo "Erro";
        }
    }
}
```

### Util to serialize list of objects:

First try:

```
function jsonSerializeList( array $arr ) {
    $res = array();

    foreach ($arr as $a) {
        $aux = get_class_vars(get_class($a));
        array_push($res, $aux);
    }
    return $res;    
}
```

Output:

```
[[],[],[]]
```

Second try:

```
function jsonSerializeList( array $arr ) {
    $res = array();

    foreach ($arr as $a) {
        $aux = get_object_vars($a);
        array_push($res, $aux);
    }
    return $res;    
}
```

Output:

```
[[],[],[]]
```

### Conclusion

My guess is that there is a problem with the class's private attributes.
In the "$ subs" object list, each position is an object of the "Sustancia.php" class:

```
class Substancia {

private $id;
private $principioAtivo;
private $nomeComercial;
private $apelidos;

public function __construct() {
    $this->apelidos = array();
}

...
```

Would it be possible to correct the "jsonSerializeList" function so that it works correctly? I really need a function that does this object serialization to use whenever necessary.

Comment: `get_object_vars()` will only return private properties when it's called inside a method of the class. Otherwise it only returns public properties.

Comment: Perhaps `JsonSerializable::jsonSerialize` may be worth looking at

Comment: `json_encode()` won't touch private properties unless you implement the JsonSerializable interface. https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php

Comment: @Sammitch i just need to implement that interface and then what ?